# KotlinNullPointerException when rotating the screen on Fragment with map and localization

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException` at line:

```
val locationmanager=context!!.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
```

When I rotate my screen. This line is in function in:

```
class MyMapFragment: Fragment(),OnMapReadyCallback
```

Comment: You should avoid using `!!` because it breaks [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html). In this case, the `context` reference is probably `null`.

Comment: @DiegoMagdaleno What to do to context not be null? I assume that both activity and fragment are recreated during screen rotation so why it would be null?

Comment: I'm not an Android specialist but you are probably trying to access the context before it's ready. To avoid the KNPE you could just make a check if `context != null`. But, to really solve your problem, you should understand why context is `null` the moment you need it. Maybe it has something to do with the Android lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity is destroyed and re-created when you rotate the phone. This means while the activity is being re-created the context will be null, and you must be trying to access it at some point during this.

I'm not sure where you have the line of code you posted, but if you want to guarantee a non-null context you should wait till the activity is created.

```
var locationmanager: LocationManager? = null   

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val context = context ?: return // this line gets a non-null context and is safer than !!

    locationmanager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

    ...
```

In general, when accessing things that are nullable in Kotlin, it is much preferred to use `?` instead of `!!` to avoid any null pointer exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Fragment can access context only after `onAttach` lifecycle method called, because it get attached to it's host activity in this lifecycle method. So, to avoid NPE you need 
in fragment

```
lateinit var locationmanager: LocationManager

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                          container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    locationmanager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false)
}
```